# MySQL : How dump is works?

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

I have a 10GB database and the dump  takes just a few minutes. 
I want to know how the system of dump works ?
Someone can tell me ?

Comment: Given decently-fast storage, why on earth should it take longer?

Comment: That said, Assoumani, you don't seem to be picking your questions well, judging by the response you're getting from the community.  I **strongly** recommend that you read our help documents - they're linked from the top of every page - particularly the [guide to asking on-topic questions](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and the [guide to asking good questions](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).  You may also find that database questions are better handled on our sister site, http://dba.stackexchange.com (though you should check their equivalent guides, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database consists of data and indices. Sometimes index can be really big. If DB have a number of big indices, then data itself is only a small part of DB.

`mysqldump` exports only data, not the indices. When DB is restored from the dump, indices are rebuilt from the scratch. Therefore 10GB DB can produce only 2GB dump. Or even less.